# Must a pointer to an instance of class A be static in class B?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, static

IDE: Eclipse Juno;
Compiler: MinGW 4.6.2;
Project: Win32

I have a *MainWindow* with two somewhat-dissimilar MDI child windows: *MdiChildWindowA* and *MdiChildWindowB*.  A third child window, *SharedWindow*, is not MDI but can be used by either MDI child window.  All are encapsulated in their own C++ classes.

To avoid proliferation of *SharedWindow*, I borrowed part of the singleton design: `MainWindowClass::GetSharedWindowInstance()` will return a pointer to an instance of *SharedWindow*, creating one if one doesn't already exist.  `MainWindow.h` includes `SharedWindow* pSharedWindow` to back up the function.  (That's as close as *SharedWindow* gets to being a singleton.)

When *MainWindow* instantiates *MdiChildWindowA* and *MdiChildWindowB*, it passes `this` to their constructors, which they save in the class variable `pMainWindow` (defined as `MainWindow*` in `MdiChildWindowA.h` and `MdiChildWindowB.h`).

`cout` of `this` in *MainWindow* matches `cout` of `pMainWindow` in the MDI child window constructors, but by the time another function calls `pMainWindow->GetSharedWindowInstance()`, `pMainWindow` has changed!  Making `pMainWindow` static seems to have solved the problem **but how did `pMainWindow` change?**

Similarly, I found that `HMODULE` and `LPPICTURE` variables had be static in `SharedWindow.h` or they would forget their values between functions in `SharedWindow.cpp`.  **Are pointer types somehow exempt from persistence as class variables?**  I thought `static` was meant to ensure one value across all instances of its class.

Edit 2013-Sep-04:
Below is my `Application.cpp` (largely copied from a tutorial).  I thought my `MainWindow` instance was created on the heap and would persist until exiting.

```
#include "MainWindow.h"

int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrev, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow )
{   MSG  msg;
    HWND hMdiClientWindow;

    MainWindow *winMain = new MainWindow( hInstance );
    if( !winMain->Run( nCmdShow ) )
    {   delete winMain;
        return 1;
    }

    hMdiClientWindow = winMain->GetMdiClientWindow();

    while( GetMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0 ) )
    {   if( ! TranslateMDISysAccel( hMdiClientWindow, &msg ) )
        {   TranslateMessage( &msg );
            DispatchMessage ( &msg );
        }
    }

    delete winMain;

    return msg.wParam;
}
```

`new MainWindow(...)` invokes `MainWindow::MainWindow()`, where `cout` shows `this` is **0xdd13a0**.

*MainWindow* is created in the call to `Run(...)`, which passes the pointer to the instance of `MainWindow` in `lpParam`:

```
bool MainWindow::Run( int nCmdShow )
{   ...
    hMainWindow = CreateWindowEx( ..., this );
    ...
}
```

In the window procedure, the pointer is saved in the instance data of *MainWindow*:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MainWindow::MainWindowProcedure( HWND hMainWindow, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{   MainWindow* pThis;

    if( Msg == WM_NCCREATE )
    {   CREATESTRUCT* pCreateStruct = (CREATESTRUCT*) lParam;
        pThis = (MainWindow*) pCreateStruct->lpCreateParams;
        SetWindowLongPtr( hMainWindow, GWL_USERDATA, (LONG) pThis );
    } else
    {   pThis = (MainWindow*) GetWindowLongPtr( hMainWindow, GWL_USERDATA );
    }
```

In `WM_CREATE`, `cout` shows `pThis` is **0xdd13a0** when it's passed to the constructors of *MdiChildWindowA* and *MdiChildWindowB*:

```
switch( Msg )
{   ...
    case WM_CREATE:
    {   unique_ptr<MdiChildWindowA> upMdiChildWindowA;
        unique_ptr<MdiChildWindowB> upMdiChildWindowB;
        ...
        up_MdiChildWindowA = unique_ptr<MdiChildWindowA>( new MdiChildWindowA( m_hInstance, pThis, [window dimensions] ) );
        up_MdiChildWindowB = unique_ptr<MdiChildWindowB>( new MdiChildWindowB( m_hInstance, pThis, [window dimensions] ) );
```

The constructors of the MDI child windows copy the `MainWindow` pointer in the parameter `pMainWindow` into the class variable `m_pMainWindow`, and `cout` shows that both contain **0xdd13a0**:

```
MdiChildWindowA::MdiChildWindowA( HINSTANCE hInstance, MainWindow* pMainWindow, ... )
{   m_pMainWindow = pMainWindow;
    ....
}
```

In `WM_CREATE` of the MDI child window procedure, `cout` shows `m_pMainWindow` still contains **0xdd13a0**.  The only other reference to `m_pMainWindow` occurs in `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLICK` where, unless I've made it static, it has somehow become **0xdd1380** (perhaps during a pass through `DefMDIChildProc(...)`?):

```
MdiChildWindowA::MdiChildWindowProcedure( ... )
{   ...
    switch( ... )
    {   ...
        case WM_LBUTTONDBLCLICK:
        {   SharedWindow* pSharedWindow;
            ...
            pSharedWindow = pThis->m_pMainWindow->GetInstanceOfSharedWindow();  // pThis points to this instance of MdiChildWindowA. cout confirms its value hasn't changed.
```

Since `m_pMainWindow` is pointing to the wrong place, the program crashes when a `SharedWindow` function is called via `pSharedWindow`.  It appears however that `GetInstanceOfSharedWindow()` exists in this bogus instance of `MainWindow` because an address is returned - but, in the code above, it's the address of `MdiChildWindowA`!

(Note: my naming convention drives people nuts so I re-typed the code with less-dangerous names.  Hopefully there are no typos.)

@brunocodutra, @Chris Hayes: I don't have enough points to comment yet, but I appreciate your ideas.

Comment: How has `pMainWindow` changed? It's most likely that you're causing a copy constructor to be invoked somewhere, so that you have identical objects at two different memory addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without the full relevant code, but I would guess *MainWindow* is being deallocated. I would further guess *MainWindow* is originaly stored in the stack, rather than the heap, because what causes the address to change is a function call (which alters the stack).

My advice: verify if either *MainWindow* or *MdiChildWindowA* and *MdiChildWindowB* (not sure which *pMainWindow* changes) are local variables and if so, change your code, so that they get allocated in the heap, i.e. dynamicaly through the use of the keyword **new**.

Answering the second question, pointers are not treated differently from any other type, in essence they are very much like integers, but their content is promptly allowed to be interpreted as memory addresses.